# smooth extensions with unique critical point

Tags: calculus

Let $f:B^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function on the unit disk
$B^{2}$ which is smooth in $B^{2}\backslash\{0\}$ and has no critical points
there. May we find a smooth function $g:B^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that
$g(x)=f(x)$ for $\left\Vert x\right\Vert \geq1/2$ and $g$ has $\leq1$ critical
points (possibly degenerated) in $B^{2}$?

References are welcome. I need this technical proposition for the estimation
of the critical points set of a smooth function with given boundary
conditions. Same question may be asked in the $n$-dimensional case.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'possibly degenerate'?

Comment: And: have you heard about degree theory?

Comment: @Thomas: It means that the unique critical point of g(x) may be degenerate, i.e. the Hessian may equal 0 there.

Comment: Degree theory says that the index of the critical set equals some number k, it doesn't claim that we have |k| geometrically different critical points. It would be the case if they were all non-degenerate.

Comment: If $f(x) = |x|$, then it is continuous and smooth away from $0$. But you cannot get a smooth extension. If your $f$ does satisfies some elliptic PDE, then there might be some smooth extensions.

Comment: @John: I can get a bell-like smooth extension with unique critical point (minimum). g and f should coincide only for $\left\Vert x\right\Vert \geq1/2$.

Comment: @t22: OH! What a misread sorry.